# sendKeys() not working with HtmlUnitDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have this code

```
public static void switchUser(HtmlUnitDriver driver, String uid) {

    WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("principal_uid"));        
    username.sendKeys(uid);
```

This worked just fine when I used it FirefoxDriver, but since I change it to HtmlUnitDriver it stopped. My problem has 2 aspects:

1. `SendingKeys()` does not fill the username field at all. Calling `username.getText()` returns blank.
2. I need the sendKeys to be finished with a press of Enter, which seems to be a hard one to HtmlUnitDriver. Calling `username.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);` gives `NullPointerException`.

Tell me a way to fix this.Could it be because username field triggers onChange javascript?

Comment: 1. `username.getText()` is supposed to return an empty String, because this is not the way text is supposed to be read from `<input>` elements. Use [`getAttribute("value")`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

Comment: Also, the NPE by HtmlUnitDriver for the Enter key appears to be an unknown bug, you could file it here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list.